# Huawei router starts acting crazy

Tags: networking, router, lan, adsl, hg

So, my Huawei HG532e was working perfectly, fast starting , great internet speed , no lag , no nothing ...But today the power went off , I unplugged the router (in case of the power coming on/off), when the power came back , I started the router but the router took about 1 min to completely boot (was 15 sec before the power outage),before the LAN lights blinks once and then the ADSL starts to blinking till the internet is on, now the LAN lights blinks three times (5 seconds delay between each blink) the Up/Downstream max rate is not stable sometimes it's at max sometimes not, depends on the router's mood,The same things happened to my previous router which was a Huawei HG530, I didn't ask about the old one because it was old(7 years), this one is also old , but shouldn't act like that. my friend have a router which is 12 years old and works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: The line speed is "retraining" which takes some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and opening my router and checking the motherboard , it appears to be a hardware problem , even flashing a new Firmware didn't fix the issue ,thus replacing the router is recommended as if it's still working but slowly it will likely to stop working after a set of time (mine did after about 6 months).

Answer (score 0):

You say the power went off, I am assuming a power outage of some sort from what you said. Assuming I am correct in my assumption, the power outage might have harmed the router some how, a voltage spike something like that.

I have had problems with routers when the power supply wasn't plugged in properly and the power kept coming and going to it. They didn't work right after that.

If you are lucky it's nothing serious, and you could try a router reset (that's assuming you have the skills to get it working again), although a lot of ISP routers are setup in a way that they will immediately run OK from a reset.

This method should work for you: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi8gc6TufPtAhUFahUIHe9KBLsQFjACegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.router-reset.com%2Finfo%2FHuawei%2FHG532e&usg=AOvVaw3wMaMgJ8z0_-LfXY4vB6ME

There is a chance there is nothing wrong with the router, and the power outage cause a problem with your ISP/line (although I am suspecting from the longer boot time this is not the case).

If a reset doesn't sort it I would start planning on a new router, my experience is it will get worse not better. Hope this helps.

Comment: the website you suggested doesn't give any special method for my router , the 30-30-30 method doesn't work on my router , booting my router while holding the reset button, puts it in upgrading mode , So ?

Comment: OK, so the general gist on the web is holding the reset button for at least 10-15 secs whilst powered on. I would go with 30 to be sure. Don't hold the reset whilst powered off if it puts it in a different mode.  If you can access the GUI, there should be the option to do a factory reset in there too. The other thing you could consider doing is upgrading to the latest firmware BUT THIS IS RISKY on a router showing problems, as if the upgrade is not completed you might brick (ruin) your router.  If you have already tried the 30-30-30 reset, you have probably already reset your router.

Comment: Yep i reset my router many times before asking here , and i did another reset after i saw your reply , the problem still persists , i tried upgrading my router but the router's firmware is specific for my ISP , the use of another ISP firmware gives an error in the Web GUI , i guess i'm limited to use the motherboard jumper , but i don't have any experience/tools with such things.
Thank you